# Fluentd-logstash integration

Tags: logstash, fluentd

I am using in fluentd out-http plugin to integrate with logstash, but I am getting the following error:

> failed to emit fluentd's log event tag="fluent.info"
>   event={"type"=>"syslog", "plugin_id"=>"object:3f923544ab40",
>   "message"=>"shutting down input type=\"syslog\"
>   plugin_id=\"object:3f923544ab40\""} error_class=ArgumentError
>   error=#

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data from fluentd to logstash you can do it using TCP.
This [open-source plugin](https://github.com/loomltd/fluent-plugin-loomsystems) will enable you to send TCP data (even secured SSL/TLS) directly to logstash TCP input (no need to use the fluentd codec).

more details on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46264096/3142017), good luck.